# App is not receiving any notification after setting it as voip app in plist file

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have done required keys in the plist file as mentioned in the docs as below

1. Open application's Info.plist file.
2. Added a new row and type in the Key field "Required background modes".
3. Expand this array and for Item 0, type in the Value field "App plays voip"

and i have the below code into my delegate method

```
// To get call status set notification
self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call) {
    // anounce that we've had a state change in our call center
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:call.callState forKey:@"callState"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CTCallStateDidChange" object:self userInfo:dict];
};

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ctCallStateDidChange:) name:@"CTCallStateDidChange" object:nil];
```

Even after setting the plist value for voip, when i make call from iphone , i dont get the above call notification into my app

pls tell me..Am i missing anything, why i dont receive any notification

Looking for your valuable suggestions

Comment: You need to start looking here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html And also, you need to put in some more research effort in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, you just set some value at xxx_info.plist, to tell system your app is those type. Detail please see help.

But notice if your app work do not look like you tell, Apple will reject your app.